# Dictionary Item is not invoking from MVC View page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco-mvc

In Umbraco I created dictionary items for language translations. When I am calling the dictionary, translation is not working. It is displaying the original text only.
I have created Dictionary items like

```
MainMenu.SubMenu.Message
English : Welcome
Denmark : velkomst
```

I am calling the dictionary item from view level

```
@Html.Raw(@umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("MainMenu.SubMenu.Message"))
```

Output: Welcome

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide a screenshot of your Umbraco section? AFAIK, Umbraco doesn't follow a nested convention for dictionary items, so it'd be good to see if MainMenu.SubMenu.Message is the name of your item, or its relative path in your tree.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the page that is loading set to Danish language? If not, it will fall back to the default language. You can set the languages on pages by right clicking on the root node of your Danish site, and selecting "Culture & Hostnames". Select Danish, and then when you look at the pages in that section, it should pull out the Danish value instead of the English one.